# How can I extract last date from a string with regexp_substr MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I try to extract the last date from a string with regexp_substr.

How can I do it?

```
select regexp_substr('08.09.11 some text around
10.10.13 AP ab 16.10.13 some text around
13.08.2014 some text around.
01.09.2014 some text around
07.11.2014 some text. around
10.02.15 some text. around
11.02.15 some text around .  (tp)', 
'[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+') as test
```

My actually result is the first date (08.09.11).

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MariaDB?  They are not the same database.

Comment: I use MariaDB and I'm stucked in this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach here is to do use `REGEXP_REPLACE` with a capture group:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('08.09.11 some text around
10.10.13 AP ab 16.10.13 some text around
13.08.2014 some text around.
01.09.2014 some text around
07.11.2014 some text. around
10.02.15 some text. around
11.02.15 some text around .  (tp)',
'^[\\s\\S]*\\s(\\d+\.\\d+\.\\d+)[\\s\\S]*$',
'\\1') AS test
```

### Demo

Here is an explanation of the regex pattern used:

```
^                       from the start of the input
    [\\s\\S]*           match all content, across newlines
    \\s                 until reaching the LAST whitespace
    (\\d+\.\\d+\.\\d+)  which is followed by the last date
                        (and capture this date in \1)
    [\\s\\S]*           consume remainder of input
$                       end of the input
```

Comment: Thaks a lot! This is it!